# Trouble getting IIS to display web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i am having no problem at all compiling/debugging my web app, but when i try to run it from my  IIS server i get this error:

```
    Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"
    Internet Information Services 7.5
    Error Summary
    HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
    The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
    Detailed Error Information
    Module  StaticFileModule
    Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
    Handler StaticFile
    Error Code  0x80070032
    Requested URL   http://student-006:80/dataentry/lomform.aspx
    Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dataentry\lomform.aspx
    Logon Method    Anonymous
    Logon User  Anonymous
    Most likely causes:
    It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all content.
    The feature you are trying to use may not be installed.
    The appropriate MIME map is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.)
    If ASP.NET is not installed.
    Things you can try:
    In system.webServer/handlers:
    Ensure that the expected handler for the current page is mapped.
    Pay extra attention to preconditions (for example, runtimeVersion, pipelineMode, bitness) and compare them to the settings for your application pool.
    Pay extra attention to typographical errors in the expected handler line.
    Please verify that the feature you are trying to use is installed.
    Verify that the MIME map is enabled or add the MIME map for the Web site using the command-line tool appcmd.exe.
    To set a MIME type, use the following syntax: %SystemRoot%\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='string',mimeType='string']
    The variable fileExtension string is the file name extension and the variable mimeType string is the file type description.
    For example, to add a MIME map for a file which has the extension ".xyz": appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.xyz',mimeType='text/plain']
    Warning: Ensure that this MIME mapping is needed for your Web server before adding it to the list. Configuration files such as .CONFIG or dynamic scripting pages such as .ASP or .ASPX, should not be downloaded directly and should always be processed through a handler. Other files such as database files or those used to store configuration, like .XML or .MDF, are sometimes used to store configuration information. Determine if clients can download these file types before enabling them.
    Install ASP.NET.
    Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.
    Links and More Information
    This error occurs when the file extension of the requested URL is for a MIME type that is not configured on the server. You can add a MIME type for the file extension for files that are not dynamic scripting pages, database, or configuration files. Process those file types using a handler. You should not allows direct downloads of dynamic scripting pages, database or configuration files.
    View more information »
```

what am i doing wrong? how can i correct this issue? i am running windows 7/iis 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like the asp.net config is up the spout.

Rerun `aspnet_regiis -i` and see what happens. This should add all the necessary settings and add the handler for .aspx pages.

To run `aspnet_regiis -i` open a command prompt (Windows + R, type cmd, hit return) and change into the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{FRAMEWORK VERSION} directory then execute the command.

e.g. for .net 4 on 64bit windows

```
> cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: Also, make sure that the application pool is configured for the appropriate version of ASP.NET.

Comment: @chris here is what i tried: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -i
Start installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).
.
An error has occurred: 0x800702e4 The requested operation requires elevation.


C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: You should run cmd with administrative privileges.